# Porting c++ from Linux to windows, '__aligned__'

Tags: c++, linux, windows, gcc, porting

I am attempting to port some code from Linux to windows, and am having trouble.

This line:

```
uint8_t patch_[patch_size_*patch_size_] __attribute__ ((aligned (16)));
```

gives me:

```
Error   C3861   'aligned': identifier not found

Error   C3646   '__attribute__': unknown override specifier
```

IS this a Linux-to-Windows issue? I cannot find a definition for either `aligned` or `__attribute__` anywhere.

(The code I am trying to port is: https://github.com/uzh-rpg/rpg_svo)

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Variable-Attributes.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a [gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.2/gcc/Variable-Attributes.html) to MSVC issue. According to [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83ythb65.aspx)., the equivalent MSVC feature would be `__declspec(align(16))`.

If your compiler supports C++11, you can also use the [`alignas`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/alignas) declaration.

Comment: Thank you! I have tried:

` uint8_t patch_[patch_size_*patch_size_] __declspec(align(16));`  and it gives me : `expected a ';'`, on `__declspec`. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: @anti According to the [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83ythb65.aspx) linked from the answer, `__declspec` goes before the declaration, so it'd be something like `__declspec(align(32)) uint8_t patch_[patch_size_*patch_size_];`